# Increase accuracy of detecting lines using OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am implementing a program to detect lines in images from a camera. The problem is that when the photo is blurry, my line detection algorithm misses a few lines. Is there a way to increase the accuracy of the `cv.HoughLines()` function without editing the parameters?

Example input image:

[image: Blurry.]

Desired image:

[image]

My current implementation:

```
def find_lines(img):
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv.dilate(gray,np.ones((3,3), np.uint8),iterations=5)
    edges = cv.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
    lines = cv.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 350)
```

Comment: In what way do you need more accuracy? More details would be helpful as would example images. You could try using a smaller angular resolution. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be a good idea to preprocess the image before giving it to `cv2.HoughLines()`. Also I think `cv2.HoughLinesP()` would be better. Here's a simple approach

- Convert image to [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)
- Apply a sharpening kernel
- [Threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) image
- Perform [morphological operations](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to smooth/filter image

---

We apply a sharpening kernel using [`cv2.filter2D()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#d-convolution-image-filtering) which gives us the general shape of the line and removes the blurred sections. Other filters can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)).

[image]

Now we threshold the image to get solid lines

[image]

There are small imperfections so we can use morphological operations with a `cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE` kernel to get clean diamond shapes

[image]

Finally to get the desired result, we [dilate](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) using the same kernel. Depending on the number of iterations, we can obtain thinner or wider lines

Left (`iterations=2`), Right (`iterations=3`)

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, sharpen_kernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(sharpen,220, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)
result = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a go

Comment: Can you explain the values for the sharpen kernel? Is this a general sharpen kernel or will the values vary depending on the picture.

Comment: It's a general sharpen kernel. Essentially to sharpen an image, a convolution is performed between a kernel and an image. In opencv, `cv2.filter2D()` essentially does this convolution. You can experiment with other kernels [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing))

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for image sharpening techniques. You'll find suggestions [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#details).
You can use different kernel operations to achieve this. OpenCV lists this C++ code [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#details)

```
 // sharpen image using "unsharp mask" algorithm
Mat blurred; double sigma = 1, threshold = 5, amount = 1;
GaussianBlur(img, blurred, Size(), sigma, sigma);
Mat lowContrastMask = abs(img - blurred) < threshold;
Mat sharpened = img*(1+amount) + blurred*(-amount);
img.copyTo(sharpened, lowContrastMask);
```

which should be fairly easy to convert to Python.